# A case of polynomial irreducibility

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Assume we have two polynomials $p(x),q(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ having degrees $m, n$ respectively. I am trying to prove that $p(x)*q(x)+ x^{m+n}$ is irreducible. Or it is not? In such case, do you have any idea how to make from $p$ and $q$ an irreducible polynomial?

Comment: How about $m=n=1,\;p=x,\;q=x$?

Comment: Perhaps you want to required that $x$ does not divide $pq$, to avoid trivial cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with $p,q$ not associated: take $p(x)=x$, $q(x)=x+1$. Then 
$$x(x+1)+x^2=x(2x+1)$$
is factored.

Answer (score 1):

Not true.

Take $q=-p$. Then $x^{2n}-p(x)^2 = (x^n+p(x))(x^n-p(x))$ is reducible.